# Foreach Loop Configuration for Displaying 2 Sets of Data

Tags: php, loops, foreach, format

I am using Simple HTML DOM to get data from a webpage that returns a page of results. I want to format it as title, then description. Right now I am using this code:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('https://www.example.com?q=randomquery');

foreach($html->find('div#resultscontainer') as $data)

//for each title
foreach($data->find('h3') as $title) {
//for each description
foreach($data->find('span.st') as $desc) {
//format code
    echo "<div class='result'>";
    echo $title;
    echo $desc;
    echo "</div>";
    }
}

?>
```

Right now the code gives me a bunch of titles, and all possible descriptions under those titles. Screenshot:

[image: Error explained in question. More titles do the same lower on the webpage.]

I would like each title to be assigned to the one correct description. I apologize if this seems simple but I am a beginner. All help is welcome, thank you.

-- Cameron

Comment: you should add at least the markup in question, or the live url if its okay, no body is going to figure out whats wrong with that snippet of code

Comment: @Ghost I am grabbing results from Google. Getting the data is not the hard part, I am having trouble formatting it after obtaining it.

Comment: the last `foreach` should be outside the second one..

Comment: @MateiMihai This will not work as there will be a big block of titles at the top while the descriptions still lay at the bottom. I am asking how the titles can be matched to the descriptions in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
foreach($html->find('div#resultscontainer') as $data) {
   $titlesAndDescriptions = array();

   // for each title
   foreach($data->find('h3') as $key => $title) {
      $titlesAndDescriptions[$key] = array('title' => $title);
   }

   // for each description
   foreach($data->find('span.st') as $key => $desc) {
      $titlesAndDescriptions[$key]['description'] = $desc;
   }

   foreach ($titlesAndDescriptions as $titleAndDescription) {
      echo "<div class='result'>";
      echo $titleAndDescription['title'];
      echo $titleAndDescription['description'];
      echo "</div>";
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I prefer this answer because it allows me to expand what data I want to separate more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Your second foreach checks the complete HTML file, not the content below your $title.

You should do something like this:

```
<?php
//for each title
foreach($data->find('h3') as $title) {
//for each description
foreach($title->parent->find('span.st') as $desc) {
//format code
    echo "<div class='result'>";
    echo $title->plaintext;
    echo $desc->plaintext;
    echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

For more, see the Examples at http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

--Edit: Because you give us a screenshot instead of the html you try to parse (lol ..!) I can only guess how the html looks like .. I edited my answer to query the siblings of the h3s..